# Find difference between two multidimensional double arrays

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have 2 multidimensional double arrays that contain X,Y,Z values from a same coordinate system.

I would like to compare the arrays and extract the different points to a new 
array/list.I tried For loop but is very slow.

Are any faster solutions to achieve my scope?

Arrays Format:

```
double [100000,3] array1;-->Columns represt X-Y-Z 

double [150000,3] array2;-->Columns represt X-Y-Z
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Well, for loop seems like the best way to go. And for larger arrays it is bound to take time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is, that you think you need some magic algorithm to do better, but you were already on the right track with the forloop.

And for the size of your array this is **predestined** to be a long task.

So to optimize the performance you can use your forloop, you just have to use it parallel like:

```
Parallel.ForEach(GetMultipleChunksFromArray(yourArray, yourOtherArray), (chunks) => 
{
    //your forloop goes here
    for (int i = 0; i < chunks.firstArrayChunk.Length; i++) {
         //comparing logic
    }
}
```

For the result you need to be a little careful, since you are running multiple compareoperations in parallel you need to have a threadsafe result like a concurrent dictionary where all differences are added.

Comment: I think that parallel would reduce the time . I am new to programming so  i have ideas but is not easy to me to apply them.